# Adding dynamic text to layout from attribute table with Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, data-driven-pages, dynamic-text

I was trying to figure out how to use dynamic text from an attribute table in a collection of Data Driven Pages in ArcGIS 10.

I've looked in the help files, but can't find anything on dynamic text from attribute tables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The only attribute table accessible through Dynamic Text is the attribute table of your Data Driven Pages index layer. I'm assuming your Data Driven Pages map book is based off of your grid layer, and if so then you're in luck.

Using a dyn tag of type 'page', you can access any property of the index layer

`<dyn type="page" property="YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_HERE"/>`

For example, to grab the 'GridName' of the current page, use:

`<dyn type="page" property="GridName"/>`

You have probably looked at [Using Dynamic Text with Data Driven Pages](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sr00000005000000.htm) in the ArcGIS help files, but you may have missed the 'Tip:' section near the end of the page that explains this.

Answer (score 0):

Labels from attribute tables are dynamic.
If you are looking for placing attibutes you want annotation.
Otherwise you just have the option to label objects with their attributes.

[Map books arcgis 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s90000002s000000.htm)

[Starting the mapbook 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s900000027000000.htm)

Answer (score -1):

You can do a few things before you run date driven pages export

**Create an index grid**

**Calculate adjacent fields**

This will give you dynamic A1,A2,A3 bingo grid generation...

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00sr00000005000000.htm

**Grid Index Features (Cartography)** 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00700000000q000000.htm

**Calculate Adjacent Fields (Cartography)** 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//007000000009000000.htm

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question... I was asking only about the text, not the grid (I already have done the grid). My question about the grid is whether the annotations from the attribute table would change when I changed the page (i.e. not displaying the attribute for A1 when I display A2). Thanks anyways...

Comment: Page Layout support - http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s900000013000000.htm

Comment: This doesn't show how to create dynamic layout text from an attribute table.