# Why is the dynamic text on data driven pages not displaying a value from the grid attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile, data-driven-pages, dynamic-text

Relating to my question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12617/how-can-i-add-dynamic-text-to-a-layout-from-an-attribute-table), I've been trying to return a value from the attribute table using the following code:

> `<dyn type="page" property="lu1p"/>`

However, even if I try to use a different attribute heading (i.e. lu2p), it only displays "[empty]". Is there something which I'm missing?

The grid index page is actually a set of irregular study areas (i.e. not perfectly square), but it hasn't effected the use of Data Driven Pages. I have looked at the help files for this but have not found any solution.

Edit: As requested, here is a screenshot:
[image]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPnU0.jpg) available here also

Edit: I'm still having this issue so if anyone could provide an alternative answer, I'd really appreciate it. I tried again in a new mxd and it worked once but then it stopped worked when I re-opened it.

Comment: so this is a duplicate question you are asking?

Comment: No, it isn't a duplicate question, it's related.

Comment: Data Driven Page Name corresponds to the current value of the attribute field set as the name field in the Setup Data Driven Pages dialog box.

Comment: I'm not trying to get the page name or number, I'm trying to return a value from the attribute table. It has been done before, but I'm having a problem with it.

Comment: can you post a screenshot please of the setup? attributes are pulled by associated pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The problem was that the shapefile was joined with a table and therefore would not display any dynamic text.

I thought that a join wouldn't impact the dynamic text but apparently it does.

Comment: Export the shapefile with the join and the new shapefile can be used as will export the joined data attribution.

Comment: I realise actually now that the join is useless and I have to somehow make the rows in the table I want to join it to into the columns of the table I'm using for data driven pages... But thanks, it will be useful in future. :)

Comment: Did you try fully qualifying the name.  Join tables need fully qualified field names such as tablename.fieldname

Comment: No, they don't work with dynamic text at all, any join on the grid features and the text will display [empty] or nothing. I'm migrating over the text with cursors today (hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

So assuming 'SApeelfinal' is defined in the setup and the dynamic text is Label_1

Any field in the DataDrivenPages index layer table can be used as dynamic text. Use the format:

```
<dyn type="page" property="Field_Name_Goes_Here"/>

<dyn type="page" property="Label_1"/>
```

So you could have different text boxes with the following dynamic text but only from **SApeelfinal** Table :

```
<dyn type="page" property="Label_1"/>
<dyn type="page" property="SUM_COL9"/>
<dyn type="page" property="SUM_COL10"/>
<dyn type="page" property="SUM_COL11"/>
```

**If you want fields from another table, then you would need to use Python scripting.**

Comment: It sort of worked -- now all it returns is nothing at all -- the fields are there (I changed the font type several times, the box of text changed size but still didn't display anything).

Comment: Could you possibly direct me to a premade script I could use? Would I just put it in the text field?

Comment: I have a pre-made python module, but it involves running a script tool to refresh the mxd layout when you want the text to be refreshed - probably more complicated than you need. Just create a new shapefile with the joined table's data, like Mapperz said.